# MudMenuItem not displaying on click on MudMenu

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, mudblazor

I am trying to create a MudMenu dynamically, deserializing a json and building the menu hierarchy as follows.
The menu is showing, however clicking the menu is not opening the submenu...

```
    <MudLayout>
    <MudAppBar Elevation="1">
        <MudMenu FullWidth="true">
            <ActivatorContent>
                <MudAvatar Size="Size.Large">
                    <MudImage class="myImage" Src="/Images/paradise_logo.png" Elevation="25"/>
                </MudAvatar>
            </ActivatorContent>
        </MudMenu>

        @if(categories != null) 
        {
            @foreach (var category in categories.AllCategories.Values)
            {
                <MudMenu StartIcon="@Icons.Material.Rounded.Grain" EndIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.KeyboardArrowDown" Label="@category.CategoryName" Color="Color.Primary" Variant="Variant.Filled">
                    <ChildContent>
                        @foreach(var subCategory in category.SubCategories) {
                            <MudMenuItem>"@subCategory.Value.CategoryName"</MudMenuItem>
                        }
                    </ChildContent>
                </MudMenu>
            }
        }

        <MudSpacer />
        <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.MoreVert" Color="Color.Inherit" Edge="Edge.End" />
    </MudAppBar>
    <MudMainContent>
        @Body
    </MudMainContent>
</MudLayout>
```

Comment: is this .Net 8?
if yes, are you using an interactive render mode?

Comment: yes .net8, i'm not familiar the interactive render mode, I'll check it out

Answer (score 0):

If you are using InterActiveServer per page/component it will not work. You need to change the `App.razor` to global Interactive server mode.

```
<Routes @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />
```

If you are using Blazor Webassembly standalone. To use `MudMenu` you need to make sure following steps have been finished.

1. `builder.Services.AddMudServices();` in the program.cs
2. Following code are added to "wwwroot/index.html"

```
...
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="_content/MudBlazor/MudBlazor.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
...
<script src="_content/MudBlazor/MudBlazor.min.js"></script>
```

3.Following component are added to Mainlayout.razor

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
<MudThemeProvider />
...
```

Then it will work.
Reference: https://www.mudblazor.com/getting-started/installation#manual-install-add-components

Comment: this is how my App.razor looks like:


```<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
```
    ```<Found Context="routeData">```
        ```<RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />```
        ```<FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />```
    ```</Found>```
    ```<NotFound>```
       ``` <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>```
        ```<LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">```
            ```<p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>```
        ```</LayoutView>```
    ```</NotFound>```
```</Router>```

Comment: @MarounSassine Ok I got that you have a Blazor Web assembly standalone project. I have modify the answer you could have a try.

Comment: I have done all these steps... and as I said in the question, the menu is showing the main subject, however the submenu is not showing when clicking on the menu itself

Comment: @MarounSassine Is the "category.SubCategories" null? Mudmenuitem is working in my test with above steps.

Comment: no, I tried it with fixed lists... submenus are not showin... v6.19.1